# Reliable way to SendInput before focusing on another Edit?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I have 2 edit controls in another dialog in a different process. For example:

Name: ____

DOB:  ____

I want to use `SendInput` to automatically input those fields because they are customized not accepting windows messages.

The steps:

1. Focus on `Name` field
2. SendInputs with name
3. Focus on `DOB` field
4. SendInputs withe DOB

the problem is sometimes part of chars of name are typed into `DBO` field. It seems step 3) was performed before 2) was done.

Add extra sleep in step 2) works. I want to know if there is more reliable way to know step 2) is *actually* done?

Comment: Are these controls are in a different process? Does that process support UI Automation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes

Comment: OK, so use UI Automation then.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't know if UIA relies on windows message, because those fields don't accept win messages like WM_SETTEXT & WM_GETTEXT, besides UIA is not friendly for invisible items in treeview.

Comment: It's kind of ironic that these details leak out now, long after the question was asked.

Comment: [`SendInput()` works asynchronously](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773). When you set focus to a control, wait for focus to actually change before continuing. When you send input, wait for it to actually arrive before continuing.